# Saving bitmap to SD card with out compressing it in android

Tags: android, bitmap, camera, store

I am using android inbuilt camera to take picture and then attaching the same picture to email, when i am testing this functionality in 1.6 device, i am able name the  picture that to be taken by in built camera, but in 2.1, the picture is having a name i.e given by device,

How to give user defined name in 2.1 inbuilt camera images..

to avoid that problem i am saving the image manually but when i try to get the image back through intent as bitmap and then saving it to sd card using compress method

this methods handles result from inbuilt camera

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
 {
  File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
    + "/test.png");
  switch (requestCode)
  {
  case PHOTO_ACTION:
   if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
   {
     addPhoto = false;
     Toast.makeText(this, "Canceled ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     break;
   } else if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
   {
    Bundle b = data.getExtras();
    Bitmap bm = (Bitmap) b.get("data");

    FileOutputStream out;
    try
     {

     out = new FileOutputStream(file);
     bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
     out.flush();
     out.close();
     scanPhoto(file.toString());
     out = null;
     addPhoto = true;
     } catch (Exception e)
      {
       e.printStackTrace();
       addPhoto = false;
      }
```

but when i am storing like this i am getting two images. one with system given name and other with name given by me. but the image one which has user defined is having less resolution so i question is how to save the bitmap with more resolution with out compressing it ..
please help.... me

Comment: I am encountering the same problem as you had. Have you managed to solve it? If yes, could you please also share your solution to me? Thanks!

Comment: I am having the same issue, found no solution till now..

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to save the bitmap without losing quality try using CompressFormat.PNG instead of JPEG, I've seen people having that problem before. Try changing:

```
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
```

with:

```
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
```

and see it it helps.

Comment: Even after setting 100 % in JPEG it had losses in clarity and quality. When I Compressed using PNG it as same clarity. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3):

Apart from Rick answer above, make sure your are providing a URI to camera intent where it can save the full image, else it will return thumb image in data parameter of intent.
So it will be like:

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
imgFile = new File("Cache directory","img.png"); //== where you want full size image
photoPickerIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile(imgFile));
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, PickPhoto);
```

This was the error that I was doing.